# Selenium - IE 8 - Unable to find element with link text

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-8, screenshotexception

In Selenium test (using version 2.40.0), I am not able to find element with link text using Internet Explorer 8 remotely. It works fine with Chrome.

Here there is (groovy) sample with a public web site.

```groovy
import org.junit.Test
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

class SampleIT {

    @Test
    void test() {
        def abilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer()
        def webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.50.26.116:4444/wd/hub"), abilities)
        webDriver.get("http://www.seznam.cz")
        webDriver.findElement(By.linkText("Firmy")).click()
    }

}
```

This is log

```
   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with link text == Firmy (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 285 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: 'fbe29a9', time: '2014-02-19 20:54:28'
System info: host: 'ghana-selenium', ip: '10.50.26.116', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: 78d4e326-4916-4aee-9834-dafbc304a8ed
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:44587/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
Command duration or timeout: 424 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: '4c5c0568b004f67810ee41c459549aa4b09c651e', time: '2014-02-19 11:13:01'
System info: host: 'ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.11.0-18-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Session ID: c542b45e-03d0-43dd-ba5f-c8748d732d85
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, webdriver.remote.sessionid=c542b45e-03d0-43dd-ba5f-c8748d732d85, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:44587/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:326)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:375)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:318)
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$findElement$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at SampleIT.test(SampleIT.groovy:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: '4c5c0568b004f67810ee41c459549aa4b09c651e', time: '2014-02-19 11:13:01'
System info: host: 'ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.11.0-18-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:125)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with link text == Firmy (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 285 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: 'fbe29a9', time: '2014-02-19 20:54:28'
System info: host: 'ghana-selenium', ip: '10.50.26.116', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: 78d4e326-4916-4aee-9834-dafbc304a8ed
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:44587/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: '4c5c0568b004f67810ee41c459549aa4b09c651e', time: '2014-02-19 11:13:01'
System info: host: 'ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.11.0-18-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:326)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:375)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:318)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.findElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(EventFiringWebDriver.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:170)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

**EDIT**
I tried it at home and it worked. But in the office, the problem lasts. Could be IE affected  by network settings, windows domain etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are probably on the right track with your edit.

From the [Selenium Internet Explorer wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver), you can see the following required configurations:

> - On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".
>     Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet Options dialog.
> - The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
> - For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

My guess is that your issue is with Protected Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium has waited only 285 milliseconds for the link to be visible on the page.You can try using [implicit or explicit](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) wait which will wait long enough to ensure if the element is present or not after the page is loaded.

And make sure `Firmy` is the exact word present in your anchor tag, even if there is an extra space it'll throw `Nosuchelement` exception. If not sure you can use `PartialLinkText`.

This is using explicit wait :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Firmy"))).click();
```

This will wait for 30 seconds for the element to be visible.

Comment: The link is exactly there, that's why I am mentioning the public web page. I think, the problem might be IE version or proxy. I have to track the reason.